# Why does echo not print the text within an if statement (windows batch file)?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following windows batch file:

```
 @echo off
 set MYVAR1=test
 set MYVAR2=
 set MYVAR3=a b c

 setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
 for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do (
    if !MYVAR%%x! == "" (
        echo Not defined
    ) else (
        echo Variable is: !MYVAR%%x!
    )
 )
```

I expect it to print the following output:

```
Variable is: test
Not defined
Variable is: a b c
```

instead I see the following output:

```
Variable is:  test
Variable is: 
Variable is: a b c
```

This does not make any sense to me! How can I change the batch script to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

One needs to enclose the delayed expression in quotation marks as well.

```
if "!MYVAR%%x!" == "" (
```

instead of

```
if !MYVAR%%x! == "" (
```

so the example code now looks like:

```
@echo off
set MYVAR1=test
set MYVAR2=
set MYVAR3=a b c

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do (
   if "!MYVAR%%x!" == "" (
    echo Not defined
    ) else (
        echo Variable is: !MYVAR%%x!
    )
 )
```

Comment: You're quick :) Just late by 20 secs.

Comment: Sometimes I am. Especially if I do not get answers within 1 minute or so.

Comment: The moment I had the chance to test your script on a virtual system you already made the answer so quick that even after figuring it out within 30 to 60 seconds, you already had made the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to your now corrected code is not to test against the empty value but to use `if defined`

```
@echo off
    set "MYVAR1=test"
    set "MYVAR2="
    set "MYVAR3=a b c"

    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do if not defined MYVAR%%x (
        echo Variable %%x Not defined
    ) else (
        echo Variable %%x is: !MYVAR%%x!
    )
```